# Proof that a finitely generated projective module over a Von Neumann Regular ring is free

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra

I'm searching for a proof that a finitely generated projective module over a Von Neumann Regular ring such that all the localizations have the same rank is free. I know that this result is true, because a friend of mine have proved it when trying to make an intuitionistic proof of the Serre's conjecture, however he did not publish it and he lost the proof that must be located among the piles of paper in his room.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Look in Ken Goodearl's book on von Neumann regular rings.

Comment: Is it true though ? A product of fields is a commutative VNR ring, but you can easily find a principal ideal which is not free..

Comment: Oops, I will delete my wrong answer. Thanks to Fred.Fred and Torsten!

Comment:  Ops, I forgot to put that the rank is constant at each localization.

Comment: This holds for all zero-dimensional commutative rings, see my answer here https://mathoverflow.net/q/323319.